# Trouble getting 'hardhat-shorthand' plugin for Hardhat to work, using 'hh' shortcut only brings up HTML help

Tags: hardhat

I tried installing the [hardhat-shorthand plugin](https://hardhat.org/guides/shorthand.html) and whenever I try using 'hh' in Git Bash it brings up this instead:

[image: HTML Help]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem. It happens because of a name conflict with the HTML Help program (C:\Windows\hh.exe). One way to fix it is by renaming the hh.exe program, for instance to hh-help.exe.

This is a protected Windows file so you do need to get the required permission to change the name. You can follow [this guide](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/you-require-permission-from-trustedinstaller.html) in order to change the permission.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do this, `hh` will work but you won't get autocomplete. This feature only works in bash, zsh and fish. If you are on windows, you can use bash under the Windows Subsystem for Linux. I haven't done that, but it's an easy thing to google.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, adding `npx` before the shorthand like this
`npx hh compile` does the trick.

Cheers